# Ubuntu запуск приложения

Tags: ubuntu

Недавно поставил Ubuntu, сейчас столкнулся с проблемой скачал приложение, установил его через центр приложений, но как запустить его не знаю, напишите как это сделать через терминал или любыми другими методами.

Comment: Что за приложение то?

Comment: AMD codeanalyst
Расширение deb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Может появиться значок в меню запуска приложений или другом системном меню.
2. Исполняемый файл или ссылка на него мог оказаться в одной из директорий, указанных в переменной окружения PATH. Тогда можно запустить из командной строки, введя имя этого файла.
3. Если ничего вышеуказанного не наблюдается, надо посмотреть, куда положен исполняемый файл, и из строки вводить его имя с полным или относительным путем.

Просьба давать больше информации: какая система, что за программа и т.д.

P.S. Я, старый больной человек, поискал в инете и нашел [README](http://developer.amd.com/tools/CodeAnalyst/codeanalystlinux/assets/CodeAnalyst-Linux-3.1-public_README.txt). Там в разделе FAQ написано

> Q: How do I start CodeAnalyst?
>
> A:
> Code Analyst is installed in
> /opt/CodeAnalyst/bin/CodeAnalyst by
> default. It may also 
>     be installed to a different directory if built with the --prefix
> option.
>     To start CodeAnalyst be sure you have root privilege unless you have
> setup 
>     non-root users to access the daemon (see next question).

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10, AMD codeanalyst Расширение deb, в меню не появилась, через терминал не могу так как не знаю куда она установилась, и не знаю имя исполняемого файла.Опишите подробнее 3 пункт.

Answer (score 2):

find / -mtime -1

Список файлов, которые сегодня (в течении суток) модифицированы. Вообще-то он будет большой, его лучше записать в файл и процедить grep-ом.